# How to sql server difference query datetime varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have variable time, format is `varchar(8)` in SQL Server

[image]

how result like this ? 
I try with `datediff`.. but I can not do it.. because variable is type varchar...

sql server 2008 r2

Comment: Which version of `sql server` you are using

Comment: Do you want the results in that form with years, months, days or is just days acceptable? Both answers posted so far assumed days only.

Answer (score 2):

Before using `Datediff` use `Convert` function to convert the `varchar` data into `date`

```
select datediff(dd,convert(date,date2),convert(date,date1))
From Yourtable
```

If you have any bad data which cannot be converted to date then who may have to filter out those data before converting to date.

If you are using `Sql Server 2012+` then use `TRY_CONVERT`

```
select datediff(dd,try_convert(date,date2),try_convert(date,date1))
From Yourtable
```

[**Sqlfiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/30365/2)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the varchar date into a proper date:

```
select datediff(day, cast(date1 as date), cast(date2 as date)) from your_table
```

Comment: thank's your answer...

i try.. but this is result...
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Then maybe your server expects a date in another format; you can try this instead  `datediff(day, convert(date, date1, 112), convert(date, date2, 112))`

Comment: i try again... but not succes...
this is result..

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    Datediff(day, 
             cast(left('20150201', 4) + '-' +
                  substring('20150201', 5, 2) + '-' +
                  right('20150201', 2) as DateTime), 
             cast(left('20150220', 4) + '-' + 
                  substring('20150220', 5, 2) + '-' + 
                  right('20150220', 2) as DateTime))
```

Try this to convert `varchar` into `datetime`

Comment: thank's your answer...
but.. not succes...this is result...

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Comment: i have tried and its work.. is your date format "yyyymmdd" or "yyyyyddmm"?

Comment: i succes..
but if the result like this...
 385 days...


i hope can like this.. 
1 years 2 month 5 days ?

Comment: hie Indra and marc.. 
i succes... 
if myquery = select, id, name, date time from tablename where id = '2'
i failed..>
if my query = select, id, name, date time from tablename 


why ?
i'm so headache...hehe
thank's very much..